# pandas split string to multiple columns based on the parts

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say, I have a pandas dataset from that I want to **split a single column** into **multiple columns dynamically** but I am getting a ValueError due to static key assignment.

> ValueError: Columns must be the same length as key

**Part of DF:**

```
amazon_category_and_sub_category
--------------------------------
Hobbies > Model > Rail
NaN
Hobbies > Model > Rail > Trains
Hobbies > Model
```

**What I am doing:**

```
df[['Category', 'Sub_Category_1','Sub_Category_2','Sub_Category_3','Sub_Category_4']] = df['amazon_category_and_sub_category'].str.split('>', expand=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to assign with column names you need to be sure of the size.

Here you have 4 columns resulting from the `split` which you try to assign to 5. This raises the error.

A programmatic variant to assign the first column of the split to "Category" and the subsequent ones to "Sub_Category_n":

```
df = df.join(df['amazon_category_and_sub_category']
               .str.split('>', expand=True)
               add_prefix('Sub_Category_')
               rename(columns={'Sub_Category_0': 'Category'})
             )
```

output:

```
  amazon_category_and_sub_category  Category Sub_Category_1 Sub_Category_2 Sub_Category_3
0           Hobbies > Model > Rail  Hobbies          Model            Rail           None
1                              NaN       NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
2  Hobbies > Model > Rail > Trains  Hobbies          Model           Rail          Trains
3                  Hobbies > Model  Hobbies           Model           None           None
```

Comment: worked as expected, just I need to type cast using this `astype(str)` for `NaN` like this `df = df.join(df['amazon_category_and_sub_category'].astype(str).str.split('>', expand=True).add_prefix('Sub_Category_').rename(columns={'Sub_Category_0': 'Category'}))
`